# calling a function inside header file

Tags: c++

In a header file someFile.h

```
    printf("hello"); //line 1
    const int a = printf("Hello"); //line 2
```

- Line 1 gives compilation error "expected constructor destructor or type conversion before '(' token"
- Line 2 compiles alright. Line 2 gets called whenever someFile.h is included in another cpp file (directly or indirectly)

Why does compiler behave differently for these two lines?

I was expecting same compiler error for both lines.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Darth-CodeX The rules are different in C. The only thing that matters is how OP compiles is, not whether it looks like C or not.

Comment: OP, why do you expect an error in the second line?

Comment: @Darth-CodeX What makes you think this is C? The error message makes it fairly clear that OP is trying to compile C++ code.

Comment: Line 2 seems to be something named "global variable initialization", and it will be stored in a special area in the output code, which will be executed as soon as the image containing that variable is loaded into execution context

Comment: you can define and initialise variables outside of a function but you can't just call a function on its own